# urllib3 part of requests package?

Tags: python, python-requests

I've recently used `requests.get` to read SharePoint details like below:

```
r = requests.post(sharepoint_contextinfo_url, auth=auth, headers=headers, verify=False)
```

Code worked as expected. But received the warning `Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised.`

Then, I used `requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()` to disable the warnings.

My question is `requests` uses `urllib3` to disable warnings? I was in assumption that `requests` and `urllib3` are two different libraries

If `urllib3` is part of requests (which I don't think so) then what are all the other `urllib3` can be used?

I am new to Python. I may be wrong. Please clarify

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Urllib3 is an independant package from request, Request is using (or better say built on top of) urllib3 and urllib3 can be used on its own.

The reason why requests exists is to make HTTP(S) requests a lot more painless for the developers.

- [urllib3 GitHub repo](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3)
- [Requests website](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

Comment: This makes sense. I used request make Http(s) requests and it was easy. But, did not aware of this info. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @KarthickRaju You're very welcome, if this answer has helped you, consider selecting it as the best answer. Regards.

Comment: I did just now :-)